# Magento2 setup/index.php from console DbConfig not found

Tags: magento2, install, setup

I'm trying to install magento2 from console. I use following:

```
php setup/index.php install
--db_host=localhost
--db_name=magento2ce 
--db_user=root
--db_pass=root
--backend_frontname=admin
--admin_username=admin
--admin_password=q111111
--admin_email=test@domain.com
--admin_firstname=admin
--admin_lastname=admin
```

And I'm getting following error:

```
Installing data.. PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig\DbConfig' not found in /var/www/m2.dev/www/magento2ee/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ForeignKey/Config/Reader.php on line 100
```

I see, that there no such file in the described directory. I have only 2 files in

> /lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/DeploymentConfig/

They are: `Reader.php` and `Writer.php`

---

When I execute

```
php bin/magento setup:install
```

with any params I'm getting

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Command "setup:install" is not defined.
  Did you mean this?
      setup:config:set
```

After installation from console when I run from browser http://magehost/index.php I'm getting following:

```
Please update your database: Run "php -f index.php update" from the Magento root/setup directory. %1The following modules are outdated:%2%3
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#1 /var/www/m2.dev/www/magento2ce/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 /var/www/m2.dev/www/magento2ce/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(58): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#3 /var/www/m2.dev/www/magento2ce/app/code/Magento/PageCache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 [internal function]: Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#5 /var/www/m2.dev/www/magento2ce/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#6 /var/www/m2.dev/www/magento2ce/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(95): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#7 /var/www/m2.dev/www/magento2ce/app/code/Magento/PageCache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(68): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#8 [internal function]: Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 /var/www/m2.dev/www/magento2ce/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(100): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#10 /var/www/m2.dev/www/magento2ce/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(124): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#11 /var/www/m2.dev/www/magento2ce/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#12 /var/www/m2.dev/www/magento2ce/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php(245): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#13 /var/www/m2.dev/www/magento2ce/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#14 {main}
```

Running update doesn't help, I got following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig::getSegment() in /var/www/m2.dev/www/magento2ee/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ForeignKey/Config/Reader.php on line 100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure the install works like that for later versions.
Try to install it via this command:

```
php bin/magento setup:install {all your params here}
```

Comment: [InvalidArgumentException]
  Command "setup:install" is not defined.
  Did you mean this?
      setup:config:set

Comment: That's strange. What version are you trying to install? If you run just `php bin/magento` you should see a list of available commands. `setup:install` should be one of them.

Comment: const VERSION = '0.42.0-beta11';

Comment: Try using the latest version. 0.74.0-beta8. It came out last friday. There is no point in still using the version you use.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I postpone this.. Return in few days.

Answer (score 0):

set the right permissions first then use the installer on the console with the parameters below

```
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} \;
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} \;
chmod u+x bin/magento;
bin/magento setup:install\
    --db-host=127.0.0.1\
    --db-name=dbname\
    --db-user=root\
    --db-password=root\
    --backend-frontname=admin\
    --admin-user=admin\
    --admin-password=„password123“\
    --admin-email=yourmail@mail.com\
    --admin-firstname=John\
    --admin-lastname=Doe\
    --use-sample-data\
    --base-url="http://mage.local“\
    --language=en_US\
    --timezone="Europe
```

omit the param --use-sample-data if you don not want to install sample data

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento indexer:reindex
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento deploy:mode:set
```

Comment: I think my issue isn't actual anymore, as it was long ago and magento don't use setup/index.php